# Angular 2 - 'get' accessor must return a value

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, carousel

I'm a newbie to Angular 2. Currently, I'm trying to build slide carousel component in Angular 2 and I'm trying to use ng2-bootstrap carousel from [here](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/carousel).

This is what I have so far in my **carousel.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation, Input, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Project} from './project';
import {ProjectService} from './project.service';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/carousel';

@Component({
    selector: 'carousel',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: [ProjectService],
    templateUrl: 'app/carousel.html'
 })
  //Template for the tag

export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
    projects: Project[];
  selectedProject: Project;
  private start = false;
    public length = Number;
  @Input() private noWrap:boolean;
  @Input() private noPause:boolean;
  @Input() private noTransition:boolean;
  @Input() public get interval():number {};

    constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private projectService: ProjectService){
     }

   getProjects() {
      this.projectService.getProjects()
        .subscribe(
              projects => this.projects = projects,
              error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
              );
      }

  ngOnInit(){
        this.getProjects();
    }

}

// class Slide implements OnInit, OnDestroy
@Component({
  selector: 'slide'
})
export class SlideComponent {
  @Input() public index:number;

  @HostBinding('class.active')
  @Input() public active:boolean;

  @HostBinding('class.item')
  @HostBinding('class.carousel-item')
  private addClass:boolean = true;
}
```

But when I run it, I get an error saying `app/carousel.component.ts(24,23): error TS2378: A 'get' accessor must return a value.` Which I'm not sure how to correct, as I basically just copied the solution from the tutorial.

The value for interval is given in file **app.component.ts**
like:

```
public interval:number = 5000;
    public noWrapSlides:boolean = false;
    public slides:Array<any> = [];
```

I'm using Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.4
Any suggestions?

Comment: which angular2 version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The following line seems wrong:

```
  @Input() public get interval():number {};
```

How come input is a getter?

Comment: More a comment for OP than Avi, this line should look like `@Input() public interval: number;` No `get`, no parenthesis after the variable name, no code block.